# Safari 5: Refused to load an object (GoogleSites flash player)

Tags: flash, safari, streaming

I made a (quick) website for a composer friend on Google Sites to be economical. I added a Flash player to the site so that his music would be streamable online.

All of this went swimmingly until Safari 5 came out.

The Flash player is not loaded on Safari 5. Worked fine on Safari 4.

I *imagine* this could be related to Google redirecting from the original resource URL, but I really don't know though.

The error console notes:

> Refused to load an object. URL found within request: "http://www.rossbauermusic.com/resources/player_mp3_normal.swf"

The URL of the requesting page is:
http://www.rossbauermusic.com/engage

Any thoughts about how to work-around this issue?
Any alternate "on request" mp3 strategies are appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, same here too, trying to embed a music player. Same error "Refused to load an object. URL found within request". Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Any updates?  I'm running into the same problem a year later, with grooveshark embeds

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google turned up some evidence that this is likely related to a WebKit bug/feature enabled in Safari 5, the XSS Auditor. A related answer is here:

[How can I get around Safari's XSS auditor for rendering remote flash objects on POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036201/how-can-i-get-around-safaris-xss-auditor-for-rendering-remote-flash-objects-on-p)

That answer discusses using the "X-XSS-Protection: 0" header.

And here's how you can disable it on the client:

[Disable XSS filter in Safari/WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197991/disable-xss-filter-in-safari-webview)

You can also send a special header along with the page, but that's probably not an option in Safari.