# Disable XSS filter in Safari/WebView

Tags: safari, webkit, xss

I'm developing a tool for XSS checking, using the Webkit WebView and Macruby.  This works great, except that occasionally Safari's XSS filter catches my URLs and refuses to execute evil scripts.  Is there a way to disable this functionality, preferably programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some digging I found the solution.  There's an undocumented, private method called 'setXSSAuditorEnabled' on WebPreferences.  So in my case, I did `view.preferences.XSSAuditorEnabled = false` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="0" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

---

I don't know how to implement the above solution, I so did this and it works.