# Header 'X-XSS-Protection: 0' not preventing error

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-headers

After submitting a form with a Vimeo video link, the video is not showing and Safari returns: `Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.` The video does show up after a refresh. This has been discussed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635403/how-to-set-http-header-x-xss-protection/). Kendall Hopkins' solution works perfectly when I add this line in my .htaccess file:

```
    Header set X-XSS-Protection 0
```

But obviously I prefer adding the header only once: after submitting the form. Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
    header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
    header($redirect);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Similar problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036201/how-can-i-get-around-safaris-xss-auditor-for-rendering-remote-flash-objects-on ?

Comment: I don't think so. Also, that question mentions a different error message. BTW, I was advised to open a new question for my problem.

Comment: what page are you setting the header in php?  the page you post from or the response from the form post?

Comment: The header is set on the response page (the target) from the form post.

Answer (score 1):

Without more of your code, I can't tell for sure, but I have the feeling that you are redirecting to a page with the `X-XSS-Protection: 0` header set on the *redirection* HTTP reply.

If I understand the interpretation of `X-XSS-Protection` correctly, you will need this header set correctly on the page you are actually redirected *to*.

Caveat: `X-XSS-Protection` is not a standard header. That said, I think Safari supports it.

Comment: Yes, this also came to my mind tonight. So I somehow need to tell the server this is an "after POST" request, so it can send the header. FF does not throw this error.